# using plotly and python to chart simple timesries but over 200K point

Tags: python, plotly

I have a big time series data which I would like to plot simple X by time(y) in pycharm (offline. need a local chart)

I was tried this code:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
data = [go.Scatter(x=data.Clients, y=data.Timestamp)]
py.iplot(data)
```

but got an error:

> Woah there! Look at all those points! Due to browser limitations, the
>   Plotly SVG drawing functions have a hard time graphing more than 500k
>   data points for line charts, or 40k points for other types of charts.
>   Here are some suggestions: (1) Use the `plotly.graph_objs.Scattergl`
>   trace object to generate a WebGl graph. (2) Trying using the image API
>   to return an image instead of a graph URL (3) Use matplotlib (4) See
>   if you can create your visualization with fewer data points
>
> If the visualization you're using aggregates points (e.g., box plot,
>   histogram, etc.) you can disregard this warning.

so I tried to google how to use `plotly.graph_objs.Scattergl` but could not find a sample to draw a simple line for huge amount of data.
I will appreciate any help

Comment: I plotly doesn't handle large data, rather it expects you to aggregate or downsample it yourself. I encounter the same issue with a plain histogram.